# What is the histogram of the log of sampled values approximating?

Tags: probability

Consider a sample of 10000 values from an exponential distribution with $\lambda = 1$.  If I take the log of the values sampled and then plot a histogram of these logs I get picture like this:

[image]

This is an approximation to some function of the pdf which is $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$. I can't work out what the exact function is that the picture is approximating however.

For those who like code, the picture can be in Python made with:

```
from scipy.stats import expon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
vals = expon.rvs(size=10000)
plt.hist(np.log(vals), bins=100)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a random variable following the exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$, and $Y=\log X$. Let $f_X$ (resp. $f_Y$) be the density of $X$ (resp. $Y$). Note that $X$ has values in $[0,+\infty)$ while $Y$ has values in $(-\infty,+\infty)$.

Then, for any measurable function $g$,

$$E(g(Y))=\int_0^{+\infty} g(\log x) f_X(x) \mathrm dx=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(y) f_X(e^y) e^y \mathrm dy$$

Hence, for $y\in(-\infty,+\infty)$,

$$f_Y(y)=e^y f_X(e^y)=\lambda e^y e^{-\lambda e^y}=\lambda e^{y-\lambda e^y}$$

The density has a maximum at $y=-\log \lambda$.

For $\lambda=1$, the density of $Y$ looks like this:

[image]

It's an instance of the [Gumbel distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution).

Note that you plotted a histogram of frequencies, hence the high values. You can plot a density histogram with the option `density` of the `hist` function of Matplotlib. See the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html).

Comment: Could you explain the "Hence" part please? The previous line you have shown how to compute the mean $E(g(Y))$.  Why does this imply that $f_Y(y) = e^Yf_X(e^y)$?

Comment: @felipa Because if for every measurable $g$ you have $E(g(Y))=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(y)\; \mathrm{something}(y)\; \mathrm dy$, then $\mathrm{something}$ is the density of $Y$.

Comment: Oh I see! That's a neat trick. Thank you.